# Jquery setting element value not working for long values (guids)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just ran into a problem where i am converting a select into `<ul><li/></ul>` format.

Now i take all the options, their values, html and classes and turn them into li.

That means the li get value attributes etc.

**The problem at hand**
It works perfectly fine when the options have integers (currently below 4 digits) and convert them. But i have another one where the select options have guids as values. When i try transform that all the values in the  become zero i.e. value="0".

Does anyone have any ideas?

My code exactly:

```
//Extract listbox
        $preferenceListBox.children().each(function () {
            var $liToAdd = $liTemplate.clone();
            console.log($(this).val());
            $liToAdd.html($(this).html()).prop("value",$(this).val()).prop("disabled", $(this).prop("disabled"));
            if ($(this).is("[disabled='disabled']") || $(this).is("[selected='selected']")) {
                $liToAdd.addClass("disabled");
            }
            if ($(this).filter(":selected") > 0) {
                $liToAdd.prop("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            $selectionList.append($liToAdd);

        });
```

---

**Update**

Sample of converted list html:

```
<ul class="selectionList"><li value="0" class="ui-draggable ui-selectable">-Select-<b class="preferenceButton">+</b></li><li value="0" class="ui-draggable ui-selectable">Canberra Central<b class="preferenceButton">+</b></li>...</ul>
```

It was created from this select:

```
<select class="preferenceListBox noSelectItem" id="areaCodeList" multiple="multiple" name="areaCodeList" size="7" style="display: none; "><option disabled="disabled" class="disabled">-Select-</option><option value="24631a28-901d-4156-b6f6-2d2b3c10c9ec">Canberra Central</option>...</select>
```

Comment: Any example of html code or, perhaps, sample GUID?

Comment: I just added examples for you

Comment: Read my answer, you can not use letters in value attribute of li tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp

> The value attribute of `<li>` is deprecated in HTML 4.01.
>
> The value attribute sets the value of a list item. The following list
>   items will increment from that number.
>
> **The value must be a number and can only be used in ordered lists
>   (`<ol>`).**
>
> The value attribute of `<li>` is not supported in HTML 4.01 Strict /
>   XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD.

ps: did you think about using `id` or `class` attribute instead of `value`?

Comment: Ah yes, perfect solution. I just changed every value into $element.data("value",*value*) and voila. Thanks! Ps. Is .data(...) a good way to do this or is it too inefficient. If so what is a better solution?

Comment: @MrJD Yes, the data is good if you do not need to use it as selector :) I thought that you might need to use your values in direct selection, but if not then data is perfect.